# CSS Color effect explanation

Tags: html, css

[image]I try to build a website and if I am correctly this part should make the img transparent and at the edges the color should be approximately like it was set there, but for some reason the edges are always white, and I don't know what I should change about it. I hope you can help me out with this.

```
body{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}

.box-one{
    width: 1370px;
    height:200px;
    left:15%;
    right: 50%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: absolute;
}

.box-two{
    width: 285px;
    height:1000px;
    right: 745px;
    position:static;
    left:-40%;
    background-color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
}

.box-three{
    width: 1200px;
    height: 1000px;
    position:static;
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-right: 55px;
    background-color: #020202;
    display: inline-block;
}

.box-four{
    width: 285px;
    height:1000px;
    position:static;
    right:100%;
    background-color: #020202;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```
    position: absolute;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(rgb(5, 31, 1) 0%, rgb(11, 34, 6) 60%, transparent 100%, transparent);
    mask-image: radial-gradient(rgb(99, 7, 7) 0%, rgb(4, 27, 4) 30%, transparent 100%, transparent);
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dungeons & Dragons</title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"><img class="background" src="CSS/Campfire2.jpg"/>
        <div class="box-one" >
            <div class="pic-one"></div>
            <div class="pic-two"></div>
            <div class="pic-three"></div>
            <div class="pic-four"></div>
            <div class="pic-five"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-two"></div>
        <div class="box-three"></div>
        <div class="box-four"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add more details like html in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: I hope it helps like it is now

Comment: I guess that the white is a default color

Comment: No, to reproduce the issue the html is necessary. Please add it like mentioned above...

Comment: Thank you for the html! Unfortunately your code actually only produces two black boxes without any images. Furthermore i still don't understand how you want the page to look. For example, what do you mean with "*the color should be approximately like it was set there*"?